# Return count before limit and skip applied with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a schema defined in mongoose. When I want to retrieve all the items I call

```
  Item
  .find()
  .limit(limit)
  .skip(skip)
  .exec(function (err, Items) {
    if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    return res.json(200, Items);
  });
```

In future I want perform some filtering and then count the number of results. How can I include the number of results in the response before limit and skip applied?

I tried including count() after find, but had no luck making it working. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe two queries are necessary, you can execute them in parallel:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
Promise.all([
    Item.find().limit(limit).skip(skip).exec(),
    Item.count().exec()
]).spread(function(items, count) {
    res.json(200, { items: items, count: count });
}, function(err) {
   handleError(res, err);
});
```

Note that I've adapted the JSON response format in order to fit in a new property containing the count -- I've changed the response from an array to `{ items: Array, count: Number }`.

Calling `.exec()` without passing a callback returns a [Mongoose Promise](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#promise_Promise). In the example above, I'm using [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) (`npm install bluebird`) to manage the asynchronous flow, but you could use any other library of your choice as well.